# No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I created a migration and updated the database without any problem. However, when I change my environment with

`$env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT='Production'`

and rerun `dotnet ef database update` it is using the new environment but showing that "The database is already up to date."

Comment: How do you know for sure it's using the new environment?

Comment: Unless the new enviroment is somewhat related to a different database, then the machine is correct :/

Comment: Sound like your database is up to date. What's your question?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Yes the migration updated the local env but I want to use the same migration and update the prod.

Comment: you can update the db only after applying a migration. Only changes in the model can change the migration.

Comment: @mason I can see the connection string value from the json file.

Comment: What OS are you using? Mind sharing a lil bit more info? :)

Comment: @Nicholas I use windows for that.When I run 'dotnet ef database update' it reads the configuration and connection string from appsettings.json and updates the database ok. However, when I change the ENV and rerun the update it says the DB is up to date. As a workaround, I changed the contents of appsetting.json by copying from appsetting.production.json and it worked. I was thinking that  specifying the ENV by $env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT='Production' would handle that.

Comment: @sonyvizio not really solving the issue long term, if you don't mind please do share more code out to us on OT. I'll try my best to help.

Answer (score -4):

You can do it like this;

First;

- Use create new 'Migration' // dotnet ef add migrations 'any name'

Second ;

- Update the database // dotnet ef database update

I hope it works :)